# OLS Regression results are compact and difficult to see. How do I enlarge or space more effectively

Tags: python, formatting, output, regression, dataspell

I am using Dataspell.

I am new to python coding and going through a course right now. I am working on regressions and each time I do a regression output, it is fairly small (web:853x496 px), to the point that coefficients, std errors, T, P>|t| [0.025 .975), are all one number (obviously they arent, but they appear that way).

Is there a way to enhance the size of the table?

Here is my code block:

```
x = sm.add_constant(x1)
results = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
results.summary()
```

*using statsmodels.api

I tried manipulate my display settings, with no luck. I tried manipulating font settings by going to
settings -> appearance and increasing the only available size which is under presentation mode, which has no effect.

I am open to anything. If there is a resource to learn about this issue and fixes, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.